# Set PivotTable filter with multiple variables

Tags: vba, excel

I have very nasty looking VBA that will create a new sheet and name that sheet based on a list, create a PivotTable in that new sheet, and then filter the PivotTable to the sheet name. The list is in columns A & B and contains blanks in both columns but the code knows to skip over those blanks.

What I am having a problem with is if the sheet name contains "0000" then it will need to filter the PivotTable with the information in column B up to the next blank. 
How the table looks:

```
AR0000RK    
        AR0030RK
        AR0063RK
        AR0082RK
        AR0085RK
        07020850
TX0000TY    
        TX0182TY
        TX0262TY
        07020830
AR0021ZZ    
AR0031ZZ    
AR0057ZZ    
AR0062ZZ    
AR0066ZZ    
AR0078ZZ    
AR0079ZZ    
AR0084ZZ    
TX0019ZZ    
TX0126ZZ    
TX0130ZZ    
TX0210ZZ    
TX0404ZZ
```

and the code:

```
Sub CreatePivotTable()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim StartPvt As String
Dim SrcData As String
Dim pvtLastRow As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim pf As String
Dim pf_Name As String
Dim pf_Field As PivotField
Dim pf_Filter As PivotFilter
Set aSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ARK_E_TEXAS")
lastRow = aSht.Range("ARK_E_TEXAS_LIST").Rows.Count
Set addPivotName = aSht.Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
Set dataRange = aSht.Range("B2:B" & lastRow)


pvtLastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW Data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

'Determine the data range you want to pivot
  SrcData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW Data").Range("A1:DU" & pvtLastRow).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

  Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Where do you want Pivot Table to start?
  StartPvt = sht.Name & "!" & sht.Range("A5").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Create Pivot Cache from Source Data
  Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=SrcData)

'Create Pivot table from Pivot Cache
  Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=StartPvt, _
    TableName:="PivotTable1")
    pvt.ManualUpdate = True

    pvt.AddFields RowFields:=Array( _
    "building_no", "budget_actvty_cd", "cost_elem_cd", "obj_class_cd", "func_cd", "vend_name", "title", "act_no")


'Create calculated Pivot Fields
    pf = "amt"
    pf_Name = "Sum of amt"
    pvt.AddDataField pvt.PivotFields("amt"), pf_Name, xlSum

    pvt.RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    pvt.ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
    pvt.TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium6"


Set pf_Field = sht.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("building_no")
    pf_Field.ClearAllFilters

Do Until pf_Field.PivotFilters.Count = 0
    pf_Field.PivotFilters(1).Delete
Loop

    *For Each addPivotName In dataRange
        If InStr("newSheetName", "0000") > 0 Then
        If addPivotName.Value <> "" Then
            Set pf_Filter = pf_Field.PivotFilters.Add(Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=addPivotName)
        Else
            Set pf_Filter = pf_Field.PivotFilters.Add(Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=newSheetName)
        End If
        End If

    Next addPivotName*

    pvt.ManualUpdate = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify if all these values (`AR0000RK`, `AR0030RK`, `TX0000TY`, `TX0182TY` and `AR0021ZZ`) are items of PivotField: `building_no`, if not let us know to which field they belong. Also could you please post a picture of the expected result.

Comment: @EEM Yes those are all apart of building_no. What I was trying to do is if the name contains "0000" then the filter will use the numbers in column B down to the next number in column A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution assumes the following:

- The procedures reside in the same workbook where the pivot tables will be created
- The `Defined Name` "ARK_E_TEXAS_LIST" holds all the Worksheets to be created and filters to be applied and follows this rules:

  • Column `A` holds the name of the worksheets to be created

  • Column `B` holds the filters to apply to Pivot Tables in each worksheet

  • The range will have only one column populated by row

  • If Column `B` is blank the Pivot Table will be filtered by Column `A

  • If Column `A` is blank the Pivot Table in the actual worksheet (i.e. last non blank) will be filtered by Column `B` 
     • The filters will be applied to Pivot Filed “building_no”
- This solution creates the worksheet as per the list, deleting any existing worksheet.
- It creates one common Pivot Cache for all Pivot Tables

As some resources used in the procedures may be new to OP, see comments in the code also I suggest to visit these pages, nevertheless let me know of any question you might have.

[Option Base Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg251511.aspx), 
[Variables & Constants](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Variables-And-Constants.html), [Excel Objects](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Objects.html),

[With Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx), 
[For...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg251601.aspx), 
[For Each...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264596.aspx),

[Range Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx), 
[Select Case Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278665.aspx)

```
Option Explicit 'Ensure to copy this line
Option Base 1 'Ensure to copy this line

Sub ARK_E_TEXAS_Process_EEM_Test()
Const kPtbDtaFld As String = "amt"
Const kPtbFltr As String = "building_no"
Const kPtbIni As String = "A5"

Dim aPtbRowFld As Variant
aPtbRowFld = Array( _
    "building_no", "budget_actvty_cd", "cost_elem_cd", _
    "obj_class_cd", "func_cd", "vend_name", "title", "act_no")

Dim Wbk As Workbook, Wsh As Worksheet
Dim rPtbSrc As Range, PtbCch As PivotCache
Dim Ptb As PivotTable, PtbFld As PivotField, PtbItm As PivotItem
Dim aWshFltr As Variant, vItm As Variant, b As Byte
Dim blShow As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Rem Set Objects
    Set Wbk = ThisWorkbook
    With Wbk
        Rem Set PivotCache
        With .Worksheets("RAW Data")
            Set rPtbSrc = .Range("A1:DU" & .Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count)
        End With
        Set PtbCch = .PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, rPtbSrc)
        Rem Set Worksheets & Filter Array
        aWshFltr = Ary_WshsFltrs_Set(.Sheets("ARK_E_TEXAS").Range("ARK_E_TEXAS_LIST"))
    End With

    Rem Process Worksheets & Filter Array
    For Each vItm In aWshFltr
        With Wbk
            Rem Delete Worksheet If Present
            On Error Resume Next
            .Sheets(vItm(1)).Delete
            On Error GoTo 0

            Rem Add Worksheet
            Set Wsh = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
            Wsh.Name = vItm(1)

            Rem Add Pivot Table
            Set Ptb = PtbCch.CreatePivotTable(Wsh.Range(kPtbIni), "Pt0")
        End With

        With Ptb
            .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
            .ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
            .TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium6"

            Rem Add Row Fields
            .AddFields RowFields:=aPtbRowFld

            Rem Add Data Fields
            .AddDataField .PivotFields(kPtbDtaFld), Function:=xlSum

            Rem Filter PivotTable
            Set PtbFld = .PivotFields(kPtbFltr)
            PtbFld.ClearAllFilters

        End With

        With PtbFld
            Select Case UBound(vItm)
            Case 1
                .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=vItm(1)

            Case Else
                For Each PtbItm In .PivotItems
                    blShow = False
                    For b = 2 To UBound(vItm)
                        If PtbItm.SourceName = vItm(b) Then
                            blShow = True
                            Exit For
                    End If: Next
                    PtbItm.Visible = blShow

    Next: End Select: End With: Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub
```

It also includes this procedure to create an Array with the data to add the Worksheets and Pivot Tables and Filter them.

```
Function Ary_WshsFltrs_Set(rWshFltr As Range) As Variant
Dim rCll As Range
Dim aWshFltr() As Variant, aItm() As String
Dim bA As Byte, bI As Byte
    bA = 0: bI = 0
    For Each rCll In rWshFltr.Columns(1).Cells
        With rCll
            If .Value2 <> Empty Then
                bI = 1
                Erase aItm
                ReDim Preserve aItm(bI)
                aItm(bI) = .Value2
                bA = 1 + bA
                ReDim Preserve aWshFltr(bA)
                aWshFltr(bA) = aItm

            Else
                bI = 1 + bI
                ReDim Preserve aItm(bI)
                aItm(bI) = .Offset(0, 1).Value2
                aWshFltr(bA) = aItm

    End If: End With: Next
    Ary_WshsFltrs_Set = aWshFltr
End Function
```

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that your code did work. It's a little slow but it is saving about 40 hours of cumulative time. 
I do have a question, can you please explain what the function is doing? Also the rWahFltr?

Comment: 1) Tests of the procedure ran in seconds, how large is the list or the DATA used by the pivot table. It could be something else slowing down the procedures. If you like to publish the workbook I can have a look at it.

Comment: 2) As the criteria applied to the defined name `ARK_E_TEXAS_LIST` is kind of complex the Function `WshsFltrs` works out the range to extract the values used to add `Sheets` and create `PivotTables` combined with the corresponding filters to be applied and puts all that in an Array then it's easier to loop through the array instead of the range. rWshFltr is the variable containing the range `ARK_E_TEXAS_LIST`.

Comment: the RAW DATA is approximately 1 million cells. Unfortunately, I can't share the RAW DATA with you but I can share the workbook. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: use something like GoogleSheets, Dropbox, etc

Comment: Here is the shared folder that it is in.

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByberqyJ4YcDeVNmaU00dy0tb0k&usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry should have told this before, but with raw data empty not much I can do. So could you just fill the first row of raw data with a sample of the data and tell me what is the last row, so I can populate it with random data but keeping the data type for each field ... Have seen your code and there are improvement to make although these do not affect performance... for that need to run the pivots...